# jQuery to pre-fill a form using tinyMCE RTE

Tags: jquery, tinymce

hope everyone is doing well.  My problem:

I have a table generated with a foreach loop, I want to be able to click on specific cell in each row, this should take the data in the cell and use it to pre-populate a tinyMCE text area in a dialog box. This is what I have so far:

The td I want to target in each row:

```
<td class="cmts" id="ID">comments</td>
```

The dialog I want to pre-fill before(or after opening):

```
<div id="cmts_dialog" name="cmnts_dialog" title="Comments">
<form id="cmnts_dialog_form" name="cmnts_dialog_form">
    <fieldset>
        <textarea id="comments_input" name="comments_input"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

I'm trying to populate the textarea by my jQuery so far doesn't work:

```
$(document).on('click','.cmnts',function(){
        $('#comments_input').val($(this).text());
})
```

I can do all the dialog stuff just figured the best method to do this is to populate the text area before I use .dialog('open'), but I'm open to all solutions

Any help appreciated.  Thanks  :]

Comment: I'm great thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found my answer in the [API docs](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.setContent) for tinyMCE

```
tinyMCE.get('comments_input').setContent($(this).text());
```